# Function to Open and Close the Overlay using single button element

Tags: javascript

I would like to open and close overlay using single button, so when the button is clicked an additional class is added, when closed the class is removed and overlay is closed.
So far I wrote the code that opens overlay and add/remove the class to the button.
Also I've created the method to close the overlay but I'm struggling to create a proper event to actually close it, so I would be happy if anyone can guide me a bit.

I think there should be an 'if' statement within the `events()` checking if the button have added class, if so, the overlay will be closed using this function `element.classList.contains("active");`

Also the button is animated, so when class is added 3 bars (hamburger icon) becomes X and this is the main reason I don't want to have separate buttons to open and close, I already achieved that but this is not what I'm looking for.

```
class OverlayNav {
    constructor() {
        this.injectHTML()  
        this.hamburgerIcon = document.querySelector(".menu-icon")
        this.events()
    }


    events() {
        this.hamburgerIcon.addEventListener("click", () => this.overlayOpen())
    }


    overlayOpen() {
        document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "100%";
        this.hamburgerIcon.classList.toggle("menu-icon--close-x")
    }
    overlayClose() {
        document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "0%";
    }


    injectHTML() {
        document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `
            <div id="myNav" class="overlay">
                <p>My Overlay</p>
            </div>
        `)
    }
}

export default OverlayNav
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a property that keeps track of the state of the nav bar.

```
constructor() {
  this.injectHTML()  
  this.hamburgerIcon = document.querySelector(".menu-icon")
  this.events()
  this.overlayVisible=true;
}
```

Then add a method that toggles the state and calls the right open/close-method:

```
toggleOverlay() {
  if (this.overlayVisible)
    this.overlayOpen();
  else
    this.overlayClose();
  this.overlayVisible=!this.overlayVisible;
  
}
```

Finally make the `events` method call `toggleOverlay()` instead of `overlayOpen()`.

```
events() {
  this.hamburgerIcon.addEventListener("click", () => this.toggleOverlay())
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much guys! This solution also works great! Like I have said before easy when is actually done by someone harder when you need to make is. Well a long way ahead of me learning JavaScript but I start to really like it. :) Thanks once again for a quick response.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a function with a `if` statement handle Opening and closing the overlay

Here is your code edited

```
class OverlayNav {
  constructor() {
    this.injectHTML();
    this.hamburgerIcon = document.querySelector(".menu-icon");
    this.events();
  }

  events() {
    this.hamburgerIcon.addEventListener("click", () => this.overlayHandle());
  }

  overlayOpen() {
    document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "100%";
    this.hamburgerIcon.classList.toggle("menu-icon--close-x");
  }
  overlayClose() {
    document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "0%";
  }
  overlayHandle() {
    if (element.classList.contains("active")) {
      this.overlayClose();
    } else {
      this.overlayOpen();
    }
  }

  injectHTML() {
    document.body.insertAdjacentHTML(
      "beforeend",
      `
          <div id="myNav" class="overlay">
              <p>My Overlay</p>
          </div>
      `
    );
  }
}

export default OverlayNav;
```

Comment: OMG! Thank you! This looks so simple when is actually done but I was not able to figure it out. I'm just learning so this is definitely a great lesson. You have made my day!

Answer (score 0):

Alternativly, a pure **HTML + CSS** solution, using only the `details` element and the `[open]` CSS attribute selector.

```css
.overlay > p {
    padding: 1rem;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 25vw
}
.overlay summary {
    padding: 1rem 0.5rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    max-height: 90vh;
    overflow: auto;
    font-size: 4em;
    list-style: none;
}
.overlay[open] summary {
    background: black;
    color: white;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    font-size: 1em;
}

.overlay[open] {
    position: fixed;
    /* top: calc(50% - 25vw); */
    left: calc(50% - 15vw);
    outline: 5000px #00000090 solid;
    border: 5px red solid;
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
    font-size: 1em
}

.overlay[open] summary::after {
    content: '❌';
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<details class="overlay">
  <summary>☰</summary>
    <p>
      Hello world!
    </p>
</details>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks! This is also interesting approach however I'm learning JS and I'm more happier with JS solutions, but I'm not sure if JS will be faster in terms of performance. Do you think CSS would be faster? HTML & CSS way will need to load the code every time the page is loaded. With JS I can make the overlay HTML to be loaded only when  the menu button is clicked, so seams to be faster, but of course require even more code to prevent default behaviour. Anyway thank you for taking your time and helping me, I will give it a go for sure!